# Pattern doesn't give correct result

Tags: java, gwt, pattern-matching, bean-validation

My problem is that I want use bean validation , so I do on my employee bean:

```
   @Pattern( regexp = "\.+",message="Name is not null") @Size(max=10,message = "Name is verylong") 
        private String name;
```

I want to check with pattern if the string is null. The problem is that when submit form if the field is length>10, it gives me the error. But if it is null it doens't five me the error. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate that the field cannot be null, you additionally need the annotation `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`:

```
        @Pattern( regexp = "\.+",message="Name is not null") 
        @Size(max=10,message = "Name is verylong") 
        @NotNull
        private String name;
```

Consider how this would work if your field was permitted to be null, but if not null it had to match a specific pattern - you would need to have some way of making a regexp that explicitly matched a null value (and Size, and other annotations would need to do the same).

Instead, nulls are not considered as needing to be checked by the built-in validation annotations - your Pattern is asking if the string is *empty* (i.e. "contains at least one character"), not null - you might want to just use Size's `min` value instead?